# js different variable same value

Tags: javascript

Currently i'm facing the following problem. In my JavaScript code, i have a function, which should calculate the weeks from now, to a given timestamp. The problem is, that the the first value has the same Value as another variable with another name. The code:

```
let myAppointment = event.data.toTime;
            console.log(myAppointment);
            let currentDate = new Date(Date.now());
            let currentTime = (convertStringDateToDate(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), 0,0,0,0)).getTime();
            let appointmentStartDate = new Date(myAppointment.getStart());
            console.log(appointmentStartDate);
            console.log(currentDate);
            let appointmentStartTime = (convertStringDateToDate(appointmentStartDate.getFullYear(), appointmentStartDate.getMonth(), appointmentStartDate.getDate(),0,0,0,0)).getTime();
            console.log('AppointmentStartTime : ' + appointmentStartTime);
            console.log('CurrentTime: ' + currentTime);
            let timeskip = appointmentStartTime - currentTime;
            console.log(timeskip + ' timeskip / 604800000 = ' + (timeskip / 604800000));
            skips = timeskip / 604800000;
            await displayCalendar(document.getElementById('wrapper'));
            console.log(skips);
            if(skips < 0){
                skips = Math.floor(skips);
                if(Math.abs(skips) != 1){
                    navigateBackward(skips);
                }

            }else{
                skips = Math.floor(skips);
                if(Math.abs(skips) != 1){
                    navigateForward(skips);
                }
            }
            cleanTable();
            displayAppointments();
});

//i think this function may be interesting too, but the error can't occur from here
function
convertStringDateToDate(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds){
    let date = new Date();
    date.setFullYear(year);
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setDate(day);
    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    date.setMilliseconds(milliseconds);
    return date;
}
```

The function from let myAppointment = ... Leads to the following console output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
 let appointmentStartTime = (convertStringDateToDate(appointmentStartDate.getFullYear(), appointmentStartDate.getMonth(), appointmentStartDate.getDate(),0,0,0,0)).getTime();
```

You set the hours, minutes, seconds all to zero - effectively turning your start date to the same value as today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your particular example, `currentDate` and `appointmentStartDate` share the same year, month, and date. When you call `let currentTime = (convertStringDateToDate(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), 0,0,0,0)).getTime();`
, you should replace `0,0,0,0` with correct values for both `currentTime` and `appointStartTime`.

To make your coding style consistent, you can use `date.getHours()`, `date.getMinutes()`, `date.getSeconds()`, and `date.getMilliseconds()` to replace those four zeroes.

Also, if you want to shorten your code, you can get rid of `convertStringDateToDate()` and merely call `getTime()` on `currentDate` and `appointStartDate`.

```
let currentDate = new Date();
let currentTime = (convertStringDateToDate(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), currentDate.getHours(),currentDate.getMinutes(),currentDate.getSeconds(),currentDate.getMilliseconds())).getTime();
console.log(currentTime); // 1537309553647
console.log(currentDate.getTime()); // 1537309553647
```